# Insert data in a WebService (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, web-services

I am working in a project with one web server. I added the reference of the web service in Visual Studio and the connection with it works perfectly. I have to insert data (8 variables) and later read 3 variables from web server.

The data to enter:

[image: The data to enter is]

This is where I have to enter from previous data

[image: This is where I have to enter de previous data]

My code:

```
'Inicializo el WebService , initialize the webservice
Dim svc_ZWS_BAS_02_COMP As New ServiceReference1.ZWS_BAS_02_COMPONENT
Dim svc_ZWS_BAS_02 As New ServiceReference1.ZWS_BAS_02
Dim svc_ZWS_BAS_02_ERR As New ServiceReference1.ZWS_BAS_02_ERROR

'ASIGNO VALORES A LAS VARIABLES DE ZWS_BAS_02_COMPONENT , store data on variables
svc_ZWS_BAS_02_COMP.AUFNR = TexNOrden.Text
svc_ZWS_BAS_02_COMP.WERKS = TexNCentro.Text
svc_ZWS_BAS_02_COMP.COMP = TexComponente.Text
svc_ZWS_BAS_02_COMP.CHARG = TexLote.Text
'svc_ZWS_BAS_02_COMP.CHARG2 = TexLoteReal.Text

Dim Peso As Double = 0
If TexPeso1.Text = "" Then
    TexPeso1.Text = 0
End If
If TexPeso2.Text = "" Then
    TexPeso2.Text = 0
End If
If CDbl(TexPeso1.Text) > CDbl(TexPeso2.Text) Then
    Peso = CDbl(TexPeso1.Text)
Else
    Peso = CDbl(TexPeso2.Text)
End If
svc_ZWS_BAS_02_COMP.BDMNG = Peso
svc_ZWS_BAS_02_COMP.MEINS = TexUnMedidaCantNotificada.Text
'end of store data to variables

'llamo al metodo   , call method
Dim proxy As New ServiceReference1.ZWS_BASClient

''le paso el usuario y el password    , ueser and pssword
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "BASCULA"
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "friasBascula"

Dim resultado = proxy.ZWS_BAS_02(svc_ZWS_BAS_02)     'doesn't work
```

I think that I have to insert the data (`vc_ZWS_BAS_02_COMP.AUFNR`, `svc_ZWS_BAS_02_COMP.WERKS`, `svc_ZWS_BAS_02_COMP.COMP` and the rest) on `I_T_BAS_COMPONENT`, but I don't know how.

Later, I have to read this data from the web service:

[image: Read error message from webservice]